# How do I programmatically add http://rubygems.org as a gem source?

Tags: rubygems

The corporate proxy at my company seems to be interfering with `https` connections to rubygems.org (but not `http` connections), causing failures when I attempt to install gems from the default gem source, https://rubygems.org. For this reason, I'm attempting to update my gem sources to replace the default source with the unsecured `http` version of rubygems.org. (And yes, I'm aware of the security implications of this.)

When I do this manually from the command line everything works fine; I just have to get past a warning message:

```
$ gem sources --add http://rubygems.org
https://rubygems.org is recommended for security over http://rubygems.org

Do you want to add this insecure source? [yn]
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to bypass this prompt when running this command from an automated script. The `gem` command doesn't have a `--yes` or `--force` option (as far as I'm aware), and attempting to use the [`yes`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) utility to get past the prompt just results in the following error message:

```
$ yes | gem sources --add http://rubygems.org
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::OperationNotSupportedError)
    Not connected to a tty and no default specified
```

How can I get through the warning message to programmatically add http://rubygems.org as a source?

Comment: I had the same problem.. Some one knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 9):

To remove the https sources:

```
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
```

If you put the following in *~/.gemrc* it will pick it up in gem env

```
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources: ["http://rubygems.org"]
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
```

gem env snippet:

```
 - GEM CONFIGURATION:
    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
    - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org"]
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
    - http://rubygems.org
```

Comment: This worked for me. Should just have to copy the .gemrc file to the location above and then your connection should be fine.

Comment: On windows 10 my .gemrc file was in /c/users/<username>

Comment: Solved! Thanks too much.

Comment: The issue is not really solved. `gem sources ---add` works for all https sources, but not for HTTP sources.  when we add HTTP source, it asks for yn. How do we remove it?

Answer (score 0):

The force option will bypass the yes/no prompt

```
gem sources -f --add http://rubygems.org
```